# Using custom bibliography styles with BibLaTex and Biber

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber

I am currently writing an article that requires me to follow a custom bibliography style, found [on this site](https://tacl2013.cs.columbia.edu/ojs/index.php/tacl/about/submissions) as a BST file  ([direct link to BST file](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~mcollins/tacl/download/acl2012.bst)). I also found a [CSL implementation](https://www.zotero.org/styles?q=acl) of the same style.

Since I would benefit greatly from the Unicode support in using BibLaTeX with Biber, I am currently in the middle of switching. Unfortunately, I haven't found a way to use a BST or CSL file with BibLaTeX.

Is my only option to try to imitate the given style specification as close as possible using the built in style options?

Answer (score 2):

The `biblatex` model is fundementally different to the classical BibTeX one. With `biblatex`, the intermediate `.bbl` file contains data but no formatting, and the latter is done purely during the typesetting run. As such, custom `.bst` files *cannot* be used with `biblatex`. The same applies to CSL or any other implementaion.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. So I guess that BibLaTeX is not an option when you have bibliography style files like these that you have to adhere to? That's kind of a bummer...