# Use custom .bst style file with biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I want to use my own bibtex style (from a .bst file) in combination with the biblatex package (I want to use this package to have separate bibliographies for each part). Since the \bibliographystyle{} command cannot be used with the biblatex package, how do I import it?

```
\documentclass[b5paper, twoside, 11pt]{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[hmargin=2.5cm,vmargin=2.5cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage[style=numeric,doi=false,isbn=false,eprint=false,url=false,firstinits=true,backend=bibtex,refsection=part]{biblatex} % used to make seperate references for each part
\addbibresource{bibfile.bib}
%\bibliographystyle{style} % <- want to include a style.bst file here

\begin{document}
\cleardoublepage
\part*{Introduction}
\Blindtext
\cite{...}
\Blindtext
\printbibliography

\part{Part I}
\Blindtext
\cite{...}
\Blindtext
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can't. `biblatex` uses a completely different system for citations and bibliography than classical BibTeX and does not allow you to use your custom `.bst` files. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/61956/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/281358/35864, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/174676/35864

Comment: If you don't need any of `biblatex`'s advanced features (that are not implemented for BibTeX), you can simply drop `biblatex` and go with the BibTeX approach of producing bibliographies (`\bibliographystyle` & `\bibliography`). If you need `biblatex`, you will have to re-implement your style with `biblatex`. There is no conversion tool or even guide available for `.bst`->`biblatex` styles. You'll have to start from generic advice such as https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12806/35864

Comment: Ok, thank you for the reply. I will try the bibunits instead of biblatex to get separate bibliographies for each part.

Comment: Would you say your question is a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/61956/35864? Can we close it as such?

Comment: To some extent, yes. My bad... Feel free to close it, the bibunits package worked out fine (except for a minor detail regarding the href package).