# Load a custom .bst file into bibTeX

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber, custom-bib

I have a .bst file which I would like to use to customise my bibliography - I am passing the backend=biber in my preamble and I can currently only choose from the in-built styles. Where should I save this .bst file and how can I load it into my package so I can use it? I am using TeXshop on Mac.

Comment: You can't use a custom `.bst` file with `biblatex`: the two approaches are orthogonal. Either you will need to use 'classical' BibTeX or modify style from LaTeX.

Comment: You can not use custom `.bst` styles with `biblatex` (your question doesn't explicitly mention `biblatex` except for the tags, but `backend=biber` is clearly a `biblatex` option). `biblatex`'s styles work entirely different than `.bst` files. If you want to use a custom `.bst` file you will have to drop `biblatex` and go back to the BibTeX way of creating bibliographies.

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/495083/35864 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/61956/35864

Comment: If I were to do as you both sat and go back to 'classical' BibTeX, how would I proceed?

Comment: Basically you'd have to follow https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/5091/35864 in reverse: Remove `\usepackage[...]{biblatex}`, replace `\addbibresource{<yourbibfile>.bib}` by `\bibliography{<yourbibfile>}` and move it to where `\printbibliography` is in your document, remove `\printbibliography`. Finally add `\bibliographystyle{<your custom .bst file>}`. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/432102/35864

Comment: I have done as you say - I am now getting the error "missing biblatex package". Is there something I should download?

Comment: Remove all temporary files (`.aux`, `.bbl`, `.bcf`, ...) and try again. Make sure to run BibTeX and not Biber on your file (you may have to follow https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864) in reverse for that.

Comment: Any news here? Can we close this as a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/432102/35864?